# Google Maps application works on emulator but not real device

Tags: android, google-maps

I am a new user here and my reputation is not enough to display some images of my app along with my question which would make it more elaborative so unfortunately just asking the question without any images of app

i am using google nexus 4 ..API 18 (android version 4.3) virtual device and had been developing this app which could run on any android device having api 11 or 11+ and have test this app on the real android device (Samsung galaxy S2 lite) but facing some problems which are

1) whenever user will enter any location name in the edit text box and click on the find button in the same activity a marker is drawn on the map below.. it works fine in the virtual device every time but on the android device at this point when ever user clicks on find button application get crash.

2) in the  the second activity  here i have made a button my location when ever user clicks on it ..it will get the gps coordinates of the device and reverse geocode it and display the location adress in one of the edit text boxes .this also works fine in virtual device .it take a moment to do every thing but in real device it does not display any thing when ever i click on the icon at the top left it shows search using gps but does not display any thing why it is taking too much time here ..
so these are the two problems which i am facing on the android device but these are working perfectly on the virtual device..

plzzz help me there i am working on my fyp and get hang here

the code for the problem no 1 is here as follow

```
package com.example.citytourguide;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TourGuide extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    Marker mark;
    LatLng latLng;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tour_guide);

        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
               googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();

          Button btn_route=(Button) findViewById(R.id.route);
          btn_route.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),ShowPath.class));
            }
        });


     // Getting reference to btn_find of the layout activity_main
        Button btn_find = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_find);
        btn_find.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                EditText loc_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                String location = loc_name.getText().toString();

                if(location.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please! Enter Something to Find...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else{

                    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                    boolean isWiFi = networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
                    if (isWiFi==true)
                    {  
                        new GeocoderTask().execute(location);
                        }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ooops! Error In Network Connection...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tour_guide, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // An AsyncTask class for accessing the GeoCoding Web Service
    protected class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>>{

        @Override
        protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
            // Creating an instance of Geocoder classtry
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
            List<Address> addresses = null;

            try {
                // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 3);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
            return addresses; 
            }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {         

            if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            // Clears all the existing markers on the map
            googleMap.clear();

            // Adding Markers on Google Map for each matching address
            for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){                

                Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);

                // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
                latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

                String addressText = String.format("%s, %s", address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",address.getCountryName());

                // Showing the marker on the Map
                Marker mark =googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(addressText));
                mark.showInfoWindow(); // displaying title on the marker          



                // Locate the first location
                if(i==0)
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));


            }           
        }   

}
    }
```

this is the file where i have access the location

```
   package com.example.citytourguide;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ShowPath extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener,LocationListener {


    AutoCompleteTextView auto_to, auto_from;
    Button btn_path, btn_loc;
    double lat,lng;
     int i = 1 ;
     int a = 1 ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_path);





        // Getting reference to btn_find of the layout activity_main
        auto_from = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.from);         
        auto_to = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.to);
        auto_from.setText(null);
        auto_to.setText(null);
        btn_path=(Button) findViewById(R.id.path);
        btn_loc=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_loc);    
        btn_path.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_loc.setOnClickListener(this);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.show_path, menu);
        MenuItem menuitem=menu.add(Menu.NONE,Menu.FIRST,Menu.NONE,"Save");
        menuitem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        return true;
    }
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId,MenuItem item)

    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Map has been concluded from "  + " to " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.path:
            String from=auto_from.getText().toString();
            String to = auto_to.getText().toString();

            if(to.equals("")&& from.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please! Enter Start and Destination properly...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else{
                ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                boolean isWiFi = networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;

                if (isWiFi==true)
                { 
                    Intent in = new Intent(ShowPath.this,ShowMap.class);

                    in.putExtra("Start", from);
                    in.putExtra("Dest", to);
                    startActivity(in);

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ooops! Error In Network Connection...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
            break;
        case R.id.btn_loc:
            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            Location location = null ;


            if(provider.contains("gps"))
            {
                // Getting Current Location From GPS
                if(auto_from.getText().toString().matches("") && (auto_to.getText().toString().matches(""))){
                    i=0 ;
                }
                else if (auto_to.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                    a=0;
                }

                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                if(location!=null)
                    onLocationChanged(location);

            }
            else
            {
                showDialog(0);

            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0, this);    
            //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
            break;
        default:
            break;

        }   //switch statement ends


    } // on click func ends

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){

        final String message = "Enable either GPS or any other location"
                + " service to find current location.  Click OK to go to"
                + " location services settings to let you do so.";
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message)
                .setTitle("Warning")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int whichButton)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int whichButton)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                "Gps services still disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).create();

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng point = new LatLng(lat,lng);
        // converting user location to address and assign it to autocomplete text box
        new ReverseGeocodingTask(getBaseContext()).execute(point);
    }

    private class ReverseGeocodingTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, String>{
        Context mContext;

        public ReverseGeocodingTask(Context context){
            super();
            mContext = context;
        }

        // Finding address using reverse geocoding
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext);
            double latitude = params[0].latitude;
            double longitude = params[0].longitude;
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            String addressText="";

            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude,1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0 ){
                Address address = addresses.get(0);

                addressText = String.format("%s, %s, %s",
                        address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                                address.getLocality(),
                                address.getCountryName());
            }
            return addressText;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String addressText) {
            if(i==0){
                auto_from.setText(addressText);
            i++ ;
            }
            else if(a==0){
                Log.d("asim","" + a);
                auto_to.setText(addressText);
            a++;
            }


        }// post execute finish
    }// class reverse geocoding finish



    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: It is good practise to try to choose a better title and keywords for your problem. That way, you are more likely to attract the attention of someone who knows something about your problem (in your case, Google Maps)

Answer (score 0):

In the second activity the real device needs much time to fetch your location (2-10 mins) depending if you are in open air or in the house.
The emulater takes the location coordinates using the Emulater control in the DDMS so, it won't take more than seconds.Try testing ur app in open air.

Comment: but at the same location if i use the google map application and click  on the location icon in the app it instantly show the icon on the map which depicts your location so why it is behaving differently for different apps at the same location ...and what about the problem no 1 do you have any solution about that one ???

Comment: Actually I don't use Google Maps in my app , I don't use the google maps apis but for the second problem The way you fetch location with might have a problem . send me all your app files at hadishaheen@hotmail.com
I will try to find a solution!

Comment: i am also posting the code of that file where i am accessing the location watch it above

Comment: I checked the code but I don't know about Google Maps Api's Sorry for this :/